# What's the limit of arrays you can create?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

What's the limit of arrays you can create? Is there a browser cap or limitation?

The idea is that I want to dynamically create an array for each employee information (includes name, active directory, employee number etc...)

Loop through employee list and create array:

```
window["arr_" + employee number]
```

Then when the user needs it, my code will call the array name based on their employee number. The button has the empn as an attribute so I can pass it:

```
console.log( window["arr_" + empn] )
```

I'm worried that I'll have more employees that I'm allowed to create arrays.

Comment: Don't worry about the size of your content, worry about the syntax...that is just pseudo code right?

Comment: Consider storing in a object instead which will give you the lookup of O(1).

Comment: Where are you creating an array? `window` is an object, you're creating properties.

Comment: Don't store these things in `window`. Create your own object to hold them. `employees[employee_number]`

Comment: Why would you put the information about each employee in an array rather than an object?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you asked, your problem is not the theoretical limit of how many things you can store in an array, it's the practical limit at which point you'll start running out of memory or the site will be too slow.  100,000 is likely a good rule of thumb.

But there are a lot of other problems here too. First of all,

```
window["anything"]
```

is not an array, it's a property on the window object.  And the window object is definitely the wrong place to store a list of employees.  It's hard to tell with so little info, but what you probably want to do is create an object:

```
var employees = {};
```

and then populate it with key:value pairs, where the key is something like "employee_"+num and the value is the object you got from whatever you're looping over:

```
employees["employee_"+number] = data
```

The result of that will be an object like:

```
{
    "employee_0" : { "name" : "John", "number": 0 }
    "employee_1" : { "name" : "Joe", "number": 1 }
}
```

and you would reference them by key, like so:

```
console.log("Employee 0's name is " + employees["employee_0"].name);
```

Hope that helps.  If you need more help, you'll need to be clearer about how you're looping over the employee data and what it looks like.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum length until "it gets slow" is totally dependent on your target machine and your actual code, so you'll need to test on that (those) platform(s) to see what is acceptable.

However, the maximum length of an array according to the ECMAEdition specification is bound by an unsigned 32-bit integer due to the ToUint32 abstract operation, so the longest possible array could have 232-1 = 4,294,967,295 = 4.29 billion element.

Comment: Maybe you mean `2^32-1`? or `2^32-1`?

Comment: Yup. That is what I meant.

Comment: And this limit also includes all the other global variables that are also in `window`.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the maximum number of properties that can be in the `window` object?

Comment: I didn't downvote, so I can just speculate: Maximum length of what? Even though the question talks about arrays, he's actually talking about the `window` object, and asking about the number of properties it can hold.

Comment: And in general, one-line answers are considered poor. Go into detail, explain why that's the limit, provide a link to the specification, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual value is, but I see the practical upper limit around 400,000.

Comment: Do you know of the exact  maximum number of properties that can be in the window object? @Barmar I tried searching it but was unable to find it. Would be useful information to know.